# How to configure GitLab-CI job so that it runs only if specific path updated?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a git repository (and a corresponding project in GitLab), that contains multiple modules, each of them is built separately (let's also say I cannot split that repository for a good reason):

```
my-project/
  module1/
    ...
    pom.xml

  module2/
    ...
    pom.xml
```

As far as I understand, GitLab CI runs all the build jobs on every push.

I want to set up two jobs, say `build_module1` and `build_module2`, so that `build_module1` runs only if anything under `module1/` is updated, and so on. What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Only thing that I can think of right now would be to disable builds on pushes, rely only on triggers and trigger builds manually from external script of some king that listens for web hook send after push to gitlab. A little bit complex but at the same time not so hard to implement.

Comment: I can also imagine putting some code into the hook so that it stores "pre-push" commit hash to a file accessible to build job scripts, and then later the build script for each job checks if there were changes to directory we're interested in since that commit. The jobs would still technically "run", they would just exit early.

Comment: I was just curious if there is a less hacky way, like a configuration option that I've missed